# PHP - How can I change the date format in all existing PHP files

Tags: php, date

I have a lot of PHP files in which I have used `date()` function in all files to format the date.

Currently I am using the format as `MM-DD-YYYY`. Now I need to change the date format to another as `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Is there any way I could change the date format in all files in a feasible way?

I know I could have used a common function for formatting, but its too late :(

Thank You

**EDIT**

Example of using `date()` function in my PHP files

Currently I am using as below,

```
date('m-d-Y', strtotime(myDateStr));
```

But I need to change in all files as,

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime(myDateStr));
```

Please suggest if there is any other possible way to do this.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you currently use the `date()` function? According to the spec, a format should be explicitly included. Can't you use a regexp on all the files in this project? Maybe you should use a single constant variable that is used as a format string in all calls of `date()`, that would save you the bother of having to change in all places.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to search and replace the string `MM-DD-YYYY` with `DD-MM-YYYY` everywhere in all the `*.php` files from a directory and its subdirectories?

Comment: It may be time to bite the bullet and do some actual hard refactoring work...

Comment: Create a dateformat configuration constant containing the value 'd-m-Y'; go through all the hard work of changing all your code to use that constant; then if you ever need to do the same exercise again, you'll only have one place where you need to change it

Comment: Any decent IDE will allow a global find and replace. NetBeans is CTRL+SHIFT+H for example. There's also command line options, writing a small script that does this (which can even be PHP running in the CLI) etc. All these options are feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Are you simply looking to go through the code of each of your php files and change the string 'm-d-Y' to 'd-m-Y'?

If so, you simply need to see if your IDE/text editor has a find and replace tool.

In Notepad and Netbeans (at least) this is Ctrl+H. Then put 'm-d-Y' in the find box and 'd-m-Y' in the replace box, then click 'Replace All'. Do this for every relevant sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you already don't have one, get an editor like [Atom](https://www.atom.io) or [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org).

> *In Atom*:
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the *Find in Project* - view.
>
> To the upper *Find in project* textbox, type `date('MM-DD-YYYY',` and to the lower *Replace in project* textbox add `date('DD-MM-YYYY',`.
>
> Click the `Replace All` - button.

> *In Notepad++*:
>
> Almost similar, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the *Find in files* - dialog. Set `Find what` to `date('MM-DD-YYYY',` and `Replace with` to `date('DD-MM-YYYY',`. Finally click `Replace in Files`.

**Note!** You might need to adjust the `Directory` to suit your needs.

---

There are other editors as well capable of doing this and the process is almost identical in every one of them. Explore them to find how to do it in the editor in question.